# how can I check a phonegap app is on active status from background?

Tags: ios, cordova

I am wondering is it possible to have an event handler which is always triggered when

an app is going to fore-ground and become active status from background status.

does phonegap provides any plugin for listening event of being re-activated?

or... is there any native way for this? any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep - check out [pause](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause) and [resume](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#resume).

Comment: yes.. this seems work for pages that has onDeviceReady function. do I need to add resume event for all pages? this seems a lot of work.. is there any work around?

Comment: If the pause and resume functions should be the same on all pages you could write a single script that all of them include.